# Cómo recorrer un arreglo de objetos sin nombre en Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, consola, ecmascript-6

Parece ser simple pero me tiene sin encontrarle la solución. Explico de qué se trata: Quiero recorrer este arreglo que se ve en la imagen de la consola, para extraerle los datos en el campo **order**:

[image: Imagen de la consola]

Según veo se trata de un arreglo de objetos y sin nombre, sólo con el índice como clave para ser recorrido, he intentado con:

```js
let arreglo = [
{order: {uno:'dummy1'}},
{order: {dos:'dummy2'}},
{order: {tres:'dummy3'}},
]

let ordenes = [];
for (let index = 0; index < arreglo.length; index++) {
    Object.keys(arreglo[index]).forEach(i => {
        ordenes.push(arreglo[index][i].order);
    });
}

console.log(ordenes);
```

Para este ejemplo yo recibo la data en la variable "arreglo" porque la data llega de un fetch, pero me sale esto cuando trato de recorrer los datos:
[image: consola resultado]

Por favor cualquier idea es bienvenida, he leído mucha documentación sobre esto en mozilla.org pero no hay algo parecido. Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar cómo se ve en la consola tu lista **sin** nombre? Si la consola lo muestra es porque tiene una referencia en memoria (nombre). Ayudaría el saber cómo llega a la consola. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras la primera imagen de la consola muestra tal y como llega del fetch.

Comment: Si llega del `fetch`, entonces tiene un nombre, por favor añade el código relevante de tu implementación de `fetch`. Tal vez así podamos darte una respuesta. Igual intuyo que tu problema es el manejo de la asincronía. Saludos

Comment: Pues parece que sí va por ahí el problema, voy a intentar una alternativa más a ver si lo puedo resolver, gracias @MauricioContreras

Answer (score 0):

- Usa un ciclo [*for of*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of) que es para elementos iterables como en este caso el vector de objetos que muestras
- Posterior con la variable que usas para obtener los objetos en cada iteración ya solo tienes que indicar la clave a la que deseas acceder con la sintaxis de: `variable.clave`, que para este caso es `order` y es a su vez la misma clave para cada uno de los 3 objetos dentro

Código

```js
    let arreglo = [
    {order: {uno:'dummy1'}},
    {order: {dos:'dummy2'}},
    {order: {tres:'dummy3'}},
    ]


    for(let elemento of arreglo) {
      console.log(elemento.order)
    }
```

Comment: El nombre al arreglo se lo puse yo precisamente "arreglo" pero originalmente no tiene nombre y ese es el problema, al no tener un nombre como acceder, no se puede referenciar.

Comment: Lo que llega es tal y como se muestra en la **consola** un arreglo sin nombre, yo le pongo el nombre arreglo porque no se puede instanciar un arreglo sin darle nombre. De hecho ese dato en bruto lo he recorrido con forEach, con map y hasta con reduce pero no me resulta.